# "In the way" vs. "On the way"

Tags: word-choice, american-english, british-english, prepositional-phrases

I hear and use both (**in the way** and **on the way**), but I am not sure which one is perfect on which situation. Please help me to understand the difference between these two (**in the way** *vs.* **on the way**).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the context is **way**, let me try to make it simple -

> *in the way* would suggest some impediment, obstruction or the like 
>   *on the way* refers to proceeding somewhere (and something coming) or on the way of journey

For instance,

> "A tough guy was *in the way* not letting me pass through the corridor." 
>   "Sure, why not? I'll meet Jane while going to my office. Her house is *on the way*."

Useful reading for *[in the way](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+way)* and *[on the way](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/on+the+way)*.

Answer (score 1):

'On the way' means 'during the journey'. We use 'to' if we want to say our destination

Example : Let's stop for lunch on the way.
            When we were on the way to France, we met Lucy!

On the way' can also mean 'getting closer to a goal'.

Example : Your parcel is on the way. (It's on its journey to you by post.)

'In the way' means 'taking up the space that someone needs'. We use 'of' to say what thing or person needs the space.

Example :     • This box is right in the way! Let's put it in the bedroom.
               • Don't stand in front of me! You're in my way.